# Passing a variable to a view in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

How can I pass `@films` to view file `films.html.erb` and display it on the view file?

```
def index
    @films = Film.select("Title, Year").order('created_at DESC');
    @htmldoc = File.read(Rails.root.join('app', 'views','films.html.erb'))
    respond_to do |format|
       format.html { render html: @htmldoc.html_safe}
    end
end
```

Comment: I don't think you need `File.read` here. Unless I'm missing something, you can render that view without reading the file. Can you show the contents of `app/views/films.html.erb`?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to render the `films.html.erb` then you don't need to open and read the file, use just the `template` option for `render` within your `index` method.

Adapt a bit your method to something like this:

```
def index
  @films = Film.select('Title, Year').order('created_at DESC')
  render template: 'view/films'
end
```

Note `view` must match with the name of the folder where's that erb file.

Comment: I would use Rails conventions in the `select` and `order` methods instead of passing strings. `@films = Film.select(:title, :year).order(created_at: :desc)`